# Run a batch file using php

Tags: php, batch-file

Below is my piece of code , on giving the tool name as the input and pressing submit , the batch file corresponding to that tool shall be executed.

```
<html> 
   <head> 
     <title>My Form</title> 
   </head> 
 <body> 
 <form action="batch.php" method=post> 

 Which tool you would like to use:
 <br> <input type="text" name="ToolName"> 
 <p> 
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Please wait!">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

BATCH.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Perv!</title>
</head>

<?php
$ToolName = $_REQUEST['ToolName'] ; 
?>
<p>
Hi <?php print $ToolName; 
//exec("cmd/c D:\workspace\execute.bat");
exec("C:\\wamp\\www\\test.bat");
//system("test.bat");
//system("cmd /c D:\\workspace\\execute.bat");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using Apache /Windows.
Please suggest any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the question or problem? If this is not working as expected, please tell us the expected result, and paste any relevant output from your error log.

Comment: The batch file is really HTM file so this probably will end in tears. 

Since you are importing a simple text file why not use "include" instead?

Comment: The batch file contains some Java commands which is not getting executed.
Error
"Exception in thread "main" '#java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Seems to me like a problem of your batch file.

Answer (score 1):

As I already commented, what you describe seems to be a problem of your batch file. But anyway, is this file supposed to just do something or to output stuff that should be displayed?

If the later is the case, note that `exec()` only returns the last line of the output. You can get all the output be providing another variable to get all the output. The official php [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.ph) of the exec() function tells you have to do this.

Answer (score -2):

as far as i could understand your question, you can try this:

```
system($ToolName);
```

You may want to specify correct path for the **$ToolName** variable.